# HTML file path references dilemma

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
/index.php  
/navbar.php // <a id="#this"></a><div id="that"></div>  
/user/search.php  
/user/register.php
```

I have this folder structure in a project I'm currently doing. and initially thought of placing ***navbar*** in a separate file for me to `include` in all other files I have. but when I `include` navbar.php in a file other than whatever is in root, relative paths won't work so I now use an absolute path. navbar.php implements Bootstrap accordion btw, my problem is with that, I can't make it work with all the file path issue I currently have.

What am I doing wrong? What should be done? and any comments on how I structure my files? would `PHP`'s `include_path` sort this thing out (reading up on this atm) ?

EDIT:
navbar.php:

```
<div id="accordion">  
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">  
    <li><a href="/index.php">HOME</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#search">SEARCH</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#register">REGISTER</a></li>  
</ul>  
<div class="collapse">
   <div id="search"> . . . </div>  
   <div id="register"> . . .</div>    
</div>  
</div>
```

index.php:

```
<?php include("navbar.php") ?>  
...some <html>
```

user/search.php:

```
<?php include("../navbar.php") ?>  
...some <html>
```

if I use *relative path* for navbar `<a href="">`, all is fine but not when I'm inside `user` folder
and if I use an *absolute path*, idk, how can I implement it properly to target a specific tag (in my case, an anchor pointing to a div) inside itself?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem. If you are using absolute paths, what issues are you having?

Comment: Can you please paste your code here how you are including ..?